# Mock Entity Framework models

Tags: testing, mocking, asp.net-web-api2, entity-framework-core, fakeiteasy

I want to fake my complex object (an object with 5 objects properties) to test the `post` method in the controller.

When I use FakeItEasy, I get the object with `null`s, and I can't insert the object to the DbContext.

So how can I fake this? Manually?

[image: Debuging my test]

My Computer DTO:

```
public class Computer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Processor processor { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Memory> memories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Disk> disks { get; set; }
    public MotherBoard motherBoard { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GPU> gpus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to answer. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question. In particular, providing sample code that exhibits the bad behaviour will help immensely.
In the meantime, there are a number of FakeitEasy questions to do with Entity Framework that you could scan in case one applies:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfakeiteasy%5D+entity+framework

Comment: `Computer` is a plain object, do not mock it, just create it with required data.

Comment: @Fabio Can you direct me to a relevant article describe your point?